# How can i jump to another def from a def

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I enter 4, it shows Living_room2 not defined, how can I let it jump to another def form first def.Code is below, appreciate if you can help.

```
def Living_room():
    print("\nLiving room contents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway, a ball of a string")
    print("1).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("2). Stairs going up")
    print("3). Dark entranceway")
    print("4). Pick Ball of string")
    choice = input(">");
    if "1" in choice:
        print(" it looks dry")
        Living_room()
    elif "2" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "3" in choice:
        room_bedroom()
    elif "4" in choice:
        print("picked up")
        Living_room2()
Living_room()
def Living_room2():
    print("\nLiving room dcontents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway")
    print("1).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("2). Stairs going up")
    print("3). Dark entranceway")
    choice = input(">");
    if "1" in choice:
        print(" it looks dry")
        Living_room2()
    elif "2" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "3" in choice:
        room_bedroom2()
Living_room2()
```

Comment: Call `Living_room()` after your definition of `Living_room2` but before you call `Living_room2()`

Comment: Cuz I want to make one option disappear, and this is an easy way I can find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Living_room2()` before that method is defined. As a best practice, you should define your methods prior to calling them. Try:

```
def Living_room():
    print("\nLiving room contents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway, a ball of a string")
    print("1).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("2). Stairs going up")
    print("3). Dark entranceway")
    print("4). Pick Ball of string")
    choice = input(">");
    if "1" in choice:
        print(" it looks dry")
        Living_room()
    elif "2" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "3" in choice:
        room_bedroom()
    elif "4" in choice:
        print("picked up")
        Living_room2()

def Living_room2():
    print("\nLiving room dcontents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway")
    print("1).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("2). Stairs going up")
    print("3). Dark entranceway")
    choice = input(">");
    if "1" in choice:
        print(" it looks dry")
        Living_room2()
    elif "2" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "3" in choice:
        room_bedroom2()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Living_room()
    Living_room2()
```

If you're already here, though, a better question might be about re-organizing your code to better reflect what you are trying to do. It looks like a choose-your-own-adventure game. Rather than looking at each "room" as its own method, consider creating a method that reads a room "state" from a data structure and then gives the user the options associated with that state. This way you can simply change a variable (something like `current_room = 2`) and avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: so, my code actually has 9 parts. you method is working on two part code,but when I just try do same as you on 9 part it not work, could you tell me why, thanks

Comment: Try creating a data structure that simplifies your code. Maybe a dict with the room names as keys, and a list of options as values.

Here's a good place to start https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Python runs from top to bottom line by line. So in your code python see it as this...

I need to create a function called `Living_room`. Great.
But then it hits `Living_room()` before it reads the line `def Living_room2()`. So now python stop at `Living_room()` and runs that call with out setting up `Living_room2`.

Change your code to this...

```
def Living_room():
   # Living_room code here
   elif "4" in choice:
        print("picked up")
        Living_room2()

def Living_room2():
   # Living_room2 code here

Living_room()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running in this order:

```
def Living_room(): # 1
    print("\nLiving room contents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway, a ball of a string")
    print("1).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("2). Stairs going up")
    print("3). Dark entranceway")
    print("4). Pick Ball of string")
    choice = input(">");
    if "1" in choice:
        print(" it looks dry")
        Living_room()
    elif "2" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "3" in choice:
        room_bedroom()
    elif "4" in choice:
        print("picked up")
        Living_room2() #3 <- Undefined
Living_room() # 2
def Living_room2():
    print("\nLiving room dcontents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway")
    print("1).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("2). Stairs going up")
    print("3). Dark entranceway")
    choice = input(">");
    if "1" in choice:
        print(" it looks dry")
        Living_room2()
    elif "2" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "3" in choice:
        room_bedroom2()
Living_room2()
```

You are calling `Living_room2()` before it being defined. Generarlly you want to write your code in the order:

1. imports
2. class definitions
3. function defintions
4. main code

so that the functions and classes are defined before anything is ran. Given this, rewrite your code as:

```
def Living_room():
    print("\nLiving room contents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway, a ball of a string")
    print("1).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("2). Stairs going up")
    print("3). Dark entranceway")
    print("4). Pick Ball of string")
    choice = input(">");
    if "1" in choice:
        print(" it looks dry")
        Living_room()
    elif "2" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "3" in choice:
        room_bedroom()
    elif "4" in choice:
        print("picked up")
        Living_room2()

def Living_room2():
    print("\nLiving room dcontents: a pot of soil, stairs going up, a dark entranceway")
    print("1).Viewing the pot of soil") 
    print("2). Stairs going up")
    print("3). Dark entranceway")
    choice = input(">");
    if "1" in choice:
        print(" it looks dry")
        Living_room2()
    elif "2" in choice:
        room_attic()
    elif "3" in choice:
        room_bedroom2()

Living_room()
Living_room2()
```